# How do i display the post type title?

Tags: custom-post-types

Hi i was wondering if there is a way that i can display the custom post type title.

For example:

I have a custom post type entitled "Pretty Little Liars" and it also shows on the homepage, but how do i get the POST TYPE title, not the title of the post to show up like a category.

For example:

Plublished in: Pretty Little Liars

is this possible?

Also i want it to link to the post type page

Comment: You got a custom post type, that's registered with the name of "Pretty Little Liars"?

Comment: Yes i do, I'm opening a blog thats all about TV shows, can you help me?

Comment: Already answered, but honestly: Why not simply add taxonomies for the different shows?

Comment: I wanted to add Post types because each post type page will have a design to fit it :)

Comment: You could conditionally switch templates. Or stylesheets. Or just append the class of the current taxonomy (see `body_class()` and `post_class()`) to your rules...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a general template tag for this task.

```
function wpse60306_get_post_type( $echo = true )
{
    static $post_types, $labels = '';

    // Get all post type *names*, that are shown in the admin menu
    empty( $post_types ) AND $post_types = get_post_types( 
        array( 
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            '_builtin'     => false,
        ),
        'objects'
    );

    empty( $labels ) AND $labels = wp_list_pluck( $post_types, 'labels' );
    $names = wp_list_pluck( $labels, 'singular_name' );
    $name = $names[ get_post_type() ];

    // return or print?
    return $echo ? print $name : $name;
}
```

#### Explanation

We got two variables declared as `static`, so we don't have to redo the task, if you're for example using it inside a loop that shows posts from different post types.

You also got an argument (`(bool) true/false`) to switch if you just want to return or right print the name.

This function *doesn't* work for built in post types (assuming you don't need it). If you need it for built in post types too, then just remove the `_builtin` argument from the function inside ↑ `get_post_types()`.

Comment: Hey Thank you very much Kaiser, but i just found a more simple solution, using this code `<?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );
echo $post_type->label ; ?>` It shows the post type name but the only problem is, i don't know how to get it to link to the post type page, can you help me with that one please?

Comment: First: Don't mess with objects, until you **really know** what you're doing. The public API (a.k.a. "Template Tags") have a reason why they exist. If you don't want that the sky falls on your head with an update, then use what ↑ I recommended/wrote for you. Second: It should be as simple as using the `the_permalink()` Template Tag.

Comment: So your code is calling all the post type titles right? and if so how do i get them to display on the homepage, on a post that's associated with the post type

Comment: Simply add `wpse60306_get_post_type()` in your loop.

Comment: Thank you very much Kaiser :) I'm hoping to launch the site in mid august Tv-Cafe.com

Comment: @TerrellAnderson Then please mark it as solution (the check mark below the arrows). If you liked it, then you can also try to upvote it.

Comment: @kaiser why do you say it's a problem to use `$post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );`?

Comment: Typo: Instead of `$pts`, change that undeclared variable to `$post_types`

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is looking for further answers here, there is a builtin wordpress function:

```
post_type_archive_title();
```

its there since 2011, reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_type_archive_title/, old reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_archive_title